# why can't I include JSONObject type instance variable in my pojo class, that will ultimately be return by spring boot method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am facing issue `Could not write JSON document: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject`. I have a following spring rest controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="dataLastRecord/{deviceNo}/{deviceType}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public InstantDataReadLastRecord getInstantDataRead_lastRecord(@PathVariable(value="deviceNo",required=true) String deviceNo,@PathVariable(value="deviceType",required=true) String deviceType) {
        logger.info("######## inside InstantDataReadLastRecord");
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        InstantDataReadLastRecord instantDataReadLastRecord = null;
        String apiKey=getApiKeyInternal();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String resourceURL = "http://19.23.22.22:8080//PService/rest/Commands/InstanData/"+deviceNo+"/"+deviceType+"/"+apiKey;
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("");
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(resourceURL, HttpMethod.GET,entity,String.class);
        try {
            if(response.getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.OK) {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
                instantDataReadLastRecord = new InstantDataReadLastRecord();
                instantDataReadLastRecord.setApiKey((String) jsonObject.get("apiKey"));
                Object obj = jsonObject.get("data");

                System.out.println(obj.toString());
                String sss = testThis(obj.toString());// removed the spaces
                JSONObject obj22 = new JSONObject(sss);
                System.out.println(obj22);
                instantDataReadLastRecord.setData(obj22);   
            }
            else {
                logger.error("ERror in instantDataReadLastRecord");
            }
            }catch(JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        logger.info("############ InstantDataReadLastRecord over!");
        //InstantDataReadLastRecord instantDataReadLastRecord2 = testThis(instantDataReadLastRecord);

        return instantDataReadLastRecord;
    }
```

As I am returning InstantDataReadLastRecord from above method I am getting below exception in my postman window:

[image]

**InstantDataReadLastRecord pojo class**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class InstantDataReadLastRecord implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6888020164144470935L;
    private String apiKey;
    private JSONObject data;
    public InstantDataReadLastRecord() {}
    public InstantDataReadLastRecord(String apiKey, JSONObject data) {
        super();
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }
    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }
    public JSONObject getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(JSONObject data) {
        this.data = data;
    }



}
```

I think the problem is occurring because I have a `JSONObject` type instance variable `data` in my `InstantDataReadLastRecord` class. And `SpringBoot` makes a `JSONObject` type return for instantDataReadLastRecord object. How can I handle this problem.

Comment: what is the data used for? i noticed it doesnt have a generic so it probably does not know how to serialize it. Usually jsonobject wraps something

Comment: data resembles this: ` "data": "{\"Apparent Power kVA\":14.4,\"Grid Duration\":7990260,\"Grid MD kW\":0.59,\"Grid MD kVA\":0.59,\"Voltage\":240,\"Device Sr.No.\":\"SMR01-4417-0002\",\"Frequency\":49.94,\"Remaining Balance\":2737.35,\"Load Relay Status\":\"Connected\",\"Timestamp\":\"2018-02-26 18:31:18\",\"Current\":60,\"Active Power kW\":14.4}"`

Comment: Use `@ResponseBody` or `@RestController`

Comment: `JSONObject` does not implement `Serializable`, so the code fails. Is there a reason why you want to use the `org.json` package instead of jackson?

Comment: @1615903 your reason/suggestion is/looks correct. can you tell me how to use jackson instead of org.json like any link or so..

Comment: why dont you make a complex type and do JSONObject<InsertTypeHere>